# Best practice for naming a thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, debugging, ide, delphi-xe

Recently I worked on a high concurrent event-driven framework (Java Akka), which will create massive `Actor` threads. When I debug an Akka application, threads have very meaningful names. It'd really awesome. When I switch back to Delphi, I feel upset that all threads are unnamed, although they are unnamed for the past 20 years already.

For all my own designed thread classes, I follow such a pattern that I define a setter `SetThreadName` and I call `NameThreadForDebugging` in the `Execute` method. This works fine so far.

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FThreadName: string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    procedure SetThreadName(const ThreadName: string);
  end;

procedure TMyThread.SetThreadName(const ThreadName: string);
begin
  FThreadName := ThreadName;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  NameThreadForDebugging(FThreadName);
  // Put normal thread execution code here
end;
```

But those instances of 3rd-party threads will stay unnamed, unless I create a descent thread class. Is there **Delphi Magic** to set `SetThreadName` to the base Thread class? I can use `Detour.pas` to force `NameThreadForDebugging(FThreadName)` be called at the first place of `Execute` method.

Any ideas?

---

**Update 1** *Thanks David for his kindly help. To help other readers to understand my question well, the question has been sightly rephrased.*

1. What was wrong with my code?

   The `NameThreadForDebugging` method is actually a static method. The second parameter `ThreadId` is optional and it equals the current thread id by default. If I do not give a `ThreadId` clearly, I might very possibly name a the current thread, not the thread I really want to name it.
2. What is the solution?

   Call `MyThread.NameThreadForDebugging('a_name', MyThread.ThreadId);` anywhere or Call `NameThreadForDebugging('a_name');` at the beginning of `TMyThread.Execute`.
3. Why so confused to make things right?

   I do not understand, why not provide a non-static version without the second `ThreadId`. If there was such a non-static version, I could not have made this mistake.

Comment: What is `FThreadName`? Where are the third party components that are out of your control going to name their threads? Hooking is the easy part. Getting the names not so much.

Comment: If I provide a `SetThreadName`, it will set a name to a private variable `FThreadName`.

Comment: I don't understand that last comment. Who will provide the names, and at what point will that happen.

Comment: Regarding your edit, the detour is easy to do. Well, it's certainly possible, let's not worry about how to do it. Although I don't think I'd detour `TThread` since there are other ways to make threads. I don't see who is going to actually set `FThreadName` though. Not to mention the fact that helpers cannot add data members, only methods. You still don't seem to grasp my point. If anyone is capable of supplying a name for the thread, then they are capable of calling `NameThreadForDebugging` directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm extemporising here, but it looks to me as though you believe that it is only possible to name a thread from code executing inside that thread. But that is not the case. In order to name a thread all you need is its ID.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/Classes.TThread.NameThreadForDebugging) gives the function signature as so:

```
class procedure NameThreadForDebugging(AThreadName: AnsiString; 
  AThreadID: TThreadID = TThreadID(-1)); static;
```

If you don't supply the optional thread ID parameter then `-1` is passed which is interpreted as meaning, *the executing thread*. Which is how you have been using `NameThreadForDebugging` thus far. However, you can just pass the thread ID. Since you clearly have thread instances, you also have their IDs at hand.

The interface that you have imagined involves calling an instance method of the thread passing the name of the thread. That is you imagine writing this code:

```
Thread.SetThreadName(ThreadName);
```

Instead of doing that, you can simply write:

```
TThread.NameThreadForDebugging(ThreadName, Thread.ThreadID);
```

If you want to use a class helper you can do it like this:

```
type
  TThreadHelper = class helper for TThread
  public
    procedure SetThreadName(const ThreadName: string);
  end;

procedure TThreadHelper.SetThreadName(const ThreadName: string);
begin
  TThread.NameThreadForDebugging(ThreadName, ThreadID);
end;
```

Frankly, I don't think I would go to such trouble. Calling `NameThreadForDebugging` seems perfectly adequate.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks for your kindly help. How could I be so blind?

Comment: Well, it took me long enough to understand the question!

Comment: If `NameThreadForDebugging` were not a static method, it could have helped to set a thread name in expected thread context.

Comment: The reason it is a class static method is exactly so that it can be called without an instance of `TThread`. It allows you to name threads  that are not `TThread` descendents.